# Python script as a service on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: python, upstart

I am facing the following  problem. I want to run a python script as a service on Ubuntu 11.10 system (already mentioned in the following link:
[Python service using Upstart on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118495/python-service-using-upstart-on-ubuntu))
I followed the steps mentioned in the above mentioned link, but i got the following error message in syslog:

```
init: script main process (21826) terminated with status 1
Jun 8 16:59:55 bilbo kernel: [263012.984531] init: script main process ended, respawning
Jun 8 16:59:55 bilbo kernel: [263013.044099] init: script main process (21827) terminated with status 1
```

The above two lines are getting repeated all the time.

On saying `sudo start script`, I get the following:

```
$ sudo start script
script start/running, process 21826
```

Following is the content of my `script.conf` placed in `/etc/init`:

```
description "Used to start python script as a service"
author "bilbo"
start on runlevel [2]
stop on runlevel [06]
exec python /home/bilbo/scripts/webserver.py
respawn
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong? Do I have to change my python code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webserver.py` is exiting with a non-zero value. By default Upstart considers this an error and so is attempting to restart the service.

As to why `webserver.py` is exiting - my guess would be that it is assuming a particular environment. When Upstart spawns a process, it clears the environment, just like `cron` and `at`, and then sets a very small number of variables, namely:

- `TERM`
- `PATH`
- and a few Upstart-specific ones (see http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#standard-environment-variables)

To see the entire job environment, add a call to `set` as shown here:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#see-the-environment-a-job-runs-in

If your python service needs other variables, you can set them using "`env`" (the Upstart stanza, *not* the shell command). See:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#env
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#export

Comment: Thanks jamesodhunt for the input. Your guess was right. In order to run the script, it needed to be run from its current directory only and not from absolute path. So just added chdir directory_path to the conf file and that was it. :D